# How to use ip address instead of local host while deploying webservices in JBOSS server

Tags: java, web-services, jboss

Actually, I have deployed my web service in the JBOSS server. I'm able to access the server by using the below url:
http://localhost:8080/CxfRestService/rest/employeeservices?empName=abc

I'm trying to access the sever by using my ip address instead of localhost.But,I'm unable to connect to the server.I'm facing page can't be displayed error.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `-b` option when starting the server?

You should also take a look here for more details: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss42FAQ

Answer (score 0):

If you were starting jboss through eclipse , i am not familiar with the way to achieve that .

The alternative is to start Jboss through Command prompt . Navigate to "bin" folder which is inside the "jboss" folder in the command prompt and execute the following command

**run.bat -b 10.27.167.135 .**

I've used random IP . Replace the IP with your IP . This will bind it to the IP address specified .